# one of which vs. one of whom

Tags: relative-clauses, wh-questions

a. We had seven employees one of whom could speak French fluently.

b. We had seven employees one of which could speak French fluently.

Which of the above sentences is grammatically correct?

I think (a) is fine. (b) seems incorrect to me, but I think it is sometimes used.

Answer (score 3):

(a) is fine,  (b) is fine grammatically, but less common since one would tend to use a pronoun like "who" or "whom" for a person, and "that" or "which" for a non-person.

This is not a strictly enforced "rule", and it is easy to find examples of  "a person that"  or

> We are a small business with five employees, one of which is looking to become pregnant. This would cripple us as a business financially. What are our rights and what can we do about this?   ([source](https://www.justanswer.com/uk-law/6zb55-small-business-five-employees-one.html))

(By the way, although this gives an example of "which", the legal advice given at that site is horrid - it suggests finding an excuse to fire an employee who is pregnant, and that is simply illegal)

Answer (score 0):

You could use either one. It depends on how you interpret the statement.

"whom" refers back to the one employee (a person).

"which" refers back to the selection (one of seven).